# php newb! php sort images by modify/creation date

Tags: php

I am new to php and never done it, but someone wrote a gallery page which has shuffle (im guessing its the sort) but I wanted to sort by date modified.

I tried to amend it through the scripts on this site but sadly i have screwed up the page.

can anyone help  with this:-

```
<ul>
<?php
    $dirname = "images/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    usort($images, 
    create_function('$a,$b','return filetime($a) - filetime($b);')
    );
    $ignore = array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"$dirname$curimg\"><img src='img.php?src=$dirname$curimg&w=300&zc=1' alt='' /></a></li>\n ";
        }
    }               
?>
</ul>
```

And I get the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function filetime() in /websites/index.php(25) : runtime-created function on line 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: You miss a m in your function name

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($images,function($a,$b){
            if($a == $b){
                return 0;
            }
            return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

you must sure the dir only file in the images dir

Comment: filetime($a)  for it  , i forget sorry  ,  hope to help you

Comment: sorry do I declare that as a variable

filetime($a)
usort($images,function($a,$b){
            if($a == $b){
                return 0;
            }
            return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
});

Comment: usort($images,function($a,$b){
            if(filetime($dirname.$a) == filetime($dirname.$b)){
                return 0;
            }
            return filetime($dirname.$a) > filetime($dirname.$b) ? 1 : -1;
});